# How can I replace value inside CDATA of an XML tag which is inside a specific tag using Java

Tags: java, xml

I have an input xml as given below.
From this xml, I want to form a new xml String by replacing the value inside CDATA of <trade_qty> tag which is under "SwapTermList" Parent tag. e.g. `<trade_qty><![CDATA[25.0]]></trade_qty>` //Need to replace 25.0 with another value that I will pass
Similarly, also replace value inside CDATA of <fixed_price> tag which is under "TermPriceList" Parent tag, which is inturn also under "SwapTermList" Parent Tag.

`<fixed_price><![CDATA[92.053]]></fixed_price>`  //REplace 92.053 with another value that I will pass

Sample XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header TransactionID="7578641ebc849609668e4b69e6b1f088c5ec0e2d0b6ae0" controllerName="CONTROLLER_1" hostIPAddress="10.21.75.203" serverEndTime="22:40:54.382" serverStartTime="22:40:54.366" serverTimeInMs="15"/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetTradeResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:TradeData" IsCompress="FALSE" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <return xsi:type="xsd:string">
        <response>
          <mhead name="TPTResGetTrade">
            <sender>TriplePointClient</sender>
          </mhead>
          <mbody>
            <data>
              <GetTrade>
                <TradeHeader table="1">
                  <trade_status_ind><![CDATA[1]]></trade_status_ind>
                  <comm_uom_cd><![CDATA[MT]]></comm_uom_cd>
                  <participant_reloaded_ind><![CDATA[1]]></participant_reloaded_ind>
                  <deal_id><![CDATA[93174763]]></deal_id>
                  <internal_ind><![CDATA[0]]></internal_ind>
                  <mirror_doc_ind><![CDATA[0]]></mirror_doc_ind>
                  <permission_ind><![CDATA[1]]></permission_ind>
                  <trade_type_cd><![CDATA[Swap (L)]]></trade_type_cd>
                  <delivery_based_ind><![CDATA[0]]></delivery_based_ind>
                  <process_group_cd><![CDATA[MUM Physical]]></process_group_cd>
                  <xch_internal_comp_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></xch_internal_comp_type_ind>
                  <trader_person_num><![CDATA[151]]></trader_person_num>
                  <strategy_num><![CDATA[4142]]></strategy_num>
                  <language_cd><![CDATA[en]]></language_cd>
                  <comm_curr_cd><![CDATA[USD]]></comm_curr_cd>
                  <inter_company_ind><![CDATA[0]]></inter_company_ind>
                  <trade_linked_ind><![CDATA[0]]></trade_linked_ind>
                  <broker2_spread_ind><![CDATA[0]]></broker2_spread_ind>
                  <cleared_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></cleared_ind>
                  <broker_spread_ind><![CDATA[0]]></broker_spread_ind>
                  <trade_dt><![CDATA[20230913000000]]></trade_dt>
                  <commission_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></commission_type_ind>
                  <notification_ind><![CDATA[0]]></notification_ind>
                  <internal_company_num><![CDATA[4392]]></internal_company_num>
                  <fx_spot_trade_ind><![CDATA[0]]></fx_spot_trade_ind>
                  <broker_company_num><![CDATA[4103]]></broker_company_num>
                  <instrument_type_cd><![CDATA[Financial Swap]]></instrument_type_cd>
                  <data_source_cd><![CDATA[XL]]></data_source_cd>
                  <confirm_approval_ind><![CDATA[0]]></confirm_approval_ind>
                  <is_delivery_upload><![CDATA[0]]></is_delivery_upload>
                  <counterpart_company_num><![CDATA[4175]]></counterpart_company_num>
                  <internal_side_ind><![CDATA[1]]></internal_side_ind>
                  <trade_num><![CDATA[902495]]></trade_num>
                  <ref1_enabled_ind><![CDATA[1]]></ref1_enabled_ind>
                  <hedge_ind><![CDATA[0]]></hedge_ind>
                  <whatif_trade_ind><![CDATA[0]]></whatif_trade_ind>
                  <xch_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></xch_type_ind>
                  <commission_amt><![CDATA[0.05]]></commission_amt>
                  <ref2_enabled_ind><![CDATA[1]]></ref2_enabled_ind>
                  <inter_comp_ind><![CDATA[0]]></inter_comp_ind>
                  <deal_name_str><![CDATA[Swap (L) from]]></deal_name_str>
                  <SwapTermList table="2">
                    <buy_sell_ind><![CDATA[1]]></buy_sell_ind>
                    <reporting_period_offset><![CDATA[0]]></reporting_period_offset>
                    <settlement_curr_cd><![CDATA[USD]]></settlement_curr_cd>
                    <term_section_cd><![CDATA[902495-1]]></term_section_cd>
                    <use_default_instruction_ind><![CDATA[1]]></use_default_instruction_ind>
                    <mtm_factor><![CDATA[100.0]]></mtm_factor>
                    <delivery_start_dt><![CDATA[20231001000000]]></delivery_start_dt>
                    <customs_duty_status_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></customs_duty_status_ind>
                    <settle_payment_term_cd><![CDATA[14 CAL NYBnk]]></settle_payment_term_cd>
                    <alt_price_conv_ind><![CDATA[0]]></alt_price_conv_ind>
                    <cmdty_cd><![CDATA[Dubai]]></cmdty_cd>
                    <strategy_num><![CDATA[4142]]></strategy_num>
                    <last_modify_dt><![CDATA[20230913124059]]></last_modify_dt>
                    <to_uom_cd><![CDATA[MT]]></to_uom_cd>
                    <pricing_schedule_ind><![CDATA[1]]></pricing_schedule_ind>
                    <source_action_ind><![CDATA[0]]></source_action_ind>
                    <term_dt><![CDATA[20230913000000]]></term_dt>
                    <deliv_sched_cd><![CDATA[Monthly]]></deliv_sched_cd>
                    <trade_term_ind><![CDATA[1]]></trade_term_ind>
                    <allocated_ind><![CDATA[0]]></allocated_ind>
                    <scheduled_ind><![CDATA[0]]></scheduled_ind>
                    <location_num><![CDATA[2566]]></location_num>
                    <timezone_cd><![CDATA[GMT]]></timezone_cd>
                    <from_uom_cd><![CDATA[BBL]]></from_uom_cd>
                    <term_input_dt><![CDATA[20230913000000]]></term_input_dt>
                    <term_num><![CDATA[6709]]></term_num>
                    <settlement_uom_cd><![CDATA[BBL]]></settlement_uom_cd>
                    <delivery_end_dt><![CDATA[20231031000000]]></delivery_end_dt>
                    <trade_qty><![CDATA[**25.0**]]></trade_qty>
                    <instrument_type_cd><![CDATA[Financial Swap]]></instrument_type_cd>
                    <delivery_start_period><![CDATA[HE01]]></delivery_start_period>
                    <delivery_end_period><![CDATA[HE24]]></delivery_end_period>
                    <use_option_model_vol_ind><![CDATA[0]]></use_option_model_vol_ind>
                    <mtm_schedule_ind><![CDATA[1]]></mtm_schedule_ind>
                    <bonafide_hedge_ind><![CDATA[0]]></bonafide_hedge_ind>
                    <bonafide_hedge_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></bonafide_hedge_type_ind>
                    <lc_required_ind><![CDATA[0]]></lc_required_ind>
                    <end_dt><![CDATA[20231031000000]]></end_dt>
                    <bonafide_claimant_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></bonafide_claimant_ind>
                    <qty_periodicity_ind><![CDATA[2]]></qty_periodicity_ind>
                    <start_dt><![CDATA[20231001000000]]></start_dt>
                    <uom_conversion_rate><![CDATA[7.231608936927271]]></uom_conversion_rate>
                    <qty_uom_cd><![CDATA[zKBBL]]></qty_uom_cd>
                    <hdg_acct_import_status_ind><![CDATA[0]]></hdg_acct_import_status_ind>
                    <extended_qty><![CDATA[25.0]]></extended_qty>
                    <volume_computation_ind><![CDATA[0]]></volume_computation_ind>
                    <TermScrList table="2">
                      <settlement_curr_cd><![CDATA[USD]]></settlement_curr_cd>
                      <price_uom_period_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></price_uom_period_ind>
                      <common_pricing_days_ind><![CDATA[0]]></common_pricing_days_ind>
                      <price_qty_category_ind><![CDATA[0]]></price_qty_category_ind>
                      <percentage_cashflow_qty_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></percentage_cashflow_qty_ind>
                      <internal_ind><![CDATA[0]]></internal_ind>
                      <delivery_based_ind><![CDATA[0]]></delivery_based_ind>
                      <trader_person_num><![CDATA[151]]></trader_person_num>
                      <period_start_dt><![CDATA[20231001000000]]></period_start_dt>
                      <term_pricing_num><![CDATA[25770]]></term_pricing_num>
                      <strategy_num><![CDATA[4142]]></strategy_num>
                      <tier_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_type_ind>
                      <implied_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></implied_cost_ind>
                      <book_upon_match_ind><![CDATA[0]]></book_upon_match_ind>
                      <do_not_apply_ra_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></do_not_apply_ra_cost_ind>
                      <rate_lookup_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_lookup_cost_ind>
                      <round_precision_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_precision_ind>
                      <cost_source_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></cost_source_ind>
                      <estimated_volume><![CDATA[100.0]]></estimated_volume>
                      <mix_defn_num><![CDATA[0]]></mix_defn_num>
                      <term_pricing_comp_num><![CDATA[27072]]></term_pricing_comp_num>
                      <effective_dt><![CDATA[20230913000000]]></effective_dt>
                      <multiplier><![CDATA[1.0]]></multiplier>
                      <mirror_scr_num><![CDATA[0]]></mirror_scr_num>
                      <period_end_dt><![CDATA[20231031000000]]></period_end_dt>
                      <pass_thru_ind><![CDATA[0]]></pass_thru_ind>
                      <actual_estimate_ind><![CDATA[0]]></actual_estimate_ind>
                      <tier_qty_periodicity_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_qty_periodicity_ind>
                      <cumulative_ind><![CDATA[0]]></cumulative_ind>
                      <period_sub_category_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></period_sub_category_ind>
                      <componentize_status_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></componentize_status_ind>
                      <tier_boundary_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_boundary_ind>
                      <hidden_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></hidden_cost_ind>
                      <round_pricing_component_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_pricing_component_ind>
                      <manual_override_ind><![CDATA[0]]></manual_override_ind>
                      <pl_allocation_rule_ind><![CDATA[0]]></pl_allocation_rule_ind>
                      <apply_precision_ind><![CDATA[1]]></apply_precision_ind>
                      <scr_num><![CDATA[104122]]></scr_num>
                      <fixed_price><![CDATA[0.05]]></fixed_price>
                      <pricingComponentCount><![CDATA[0]]></pricingComponentCount>
                      <input_dt><![CDATA[20230913000000]]></input_dt>
                      <demand_charge_ind><![CDATA[0]]></demand_charge_ind>
                      <cost_revenue_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></cost_revenue_ind>
                      <payment_due_dt><![CDATA[20230913000000]]></payment_due_dt>
                      <scr_generated_ind><![CDATA[1]]></scr_generated_ind>
                      <pricing_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></pricing_type_ind>
                      <estimate_audit_num><![CDATA[19328]]></estimate_audit_num>
                      <comp_function_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></comp_function_ind>
                      <use_pricing_dt_ind><![CDATA[0]]></use_pricing_dt_ind>
                      <company_num><![CDATA[4103]]></company_num>
                      <floor_book_upon_match_ind><![CDATA[0]]></floor_book_upon_match_ind>
                      <complex_charges_ind><![CDATA[0]]></complex_charges_ind>
                      <balance_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></balance_cost_ind>
                      <rate_override_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_override_ind>
                      <cost_type_cd><![CDATA[Broker Fee]]></cost_type_cd>
                      <fx_rate_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></fx_rate_type_ind>
                      <pricing_period_tier_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></pricing_period_tier_ind>
                      <tier_qty_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_qty_type_ind>
                      <time_based_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></time_based_cost_ind>
                      <price_uom_cd><![CDATA[MT]]></price_uom_cd>
                      <internal_company_num><![CDATA[4392]]></internal_company_num>
                      <ic_mirror_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></ic_mirror_cost_ind>
                      <ic_scr_mirror_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></ic_scr_mirror_cost_ind>
                      <rate_lookup_cost_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_lookup_cost_type_ind>
                      <data_source_cd><![CDATA[XL]]></data_source_cd>
                      <price_curr_cd><![CDATA[USD]]></price_curr_cd>
                      <round_pricing_rule_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_pricing_rule_ind>
                      <broker_type_ind><![CDATA[1]]></broker_type_ind>
                      <inter_comp_ind><![CDATA[0]]></inter_comp_ind>
                      <retain_realized_ind><![CDATA[0]]></retain_realized_ind>
                    </TermScrList>
                    <TermUdfList table="2">
                      <udf_value><![CDATA[2]]></udf_value>
                      <operation><![CDATA[-1]]></operation>
                      <udf_cd><![CDATA[Deal Time]]></udf_cd>
                    </TermUdfList>
                    <TermUdfList table="2">
                      <udf_value><![CDATA[odcril_cgmlTradesINT_rel_files_202309130251.csv]]></udf_value>
                      <operation><![CDATA[-1]]></operation>
                      <udf_cd><![CDATA[File Name1]]></udf_cd>
                    </TermUdfList>
                    <TermMtmList table="2">
                      <price_uom_period_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></price_uom_period_ind>
                      <common_pricing_days_ind><![CDATA[0]]></common_pricing_days_ind>
                      <price_qty_category_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></price_qty_category_ind>
                      <percentage_cashflow_qty_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></percentage_cashflow_qty_ind>
                      <delivery_based_ind><![CDATA[0]]></delivery_based_ind>
                      <period_start_dt><![CDATA[20231001000000]]></period_start_dt>
                      <term_pricing_num><![CDATA[25769]]></term_pricing_num>
                      <tier_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_type_ind>
                      <implied_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></implied_cost_ind>
                      <do_not_apply_ra_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></do_not_apply_ra_cost_ind>
                      <rate_lookup_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_lookup_cost_ind>
                      <round_precision_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_precision_ind>
                      <cost_source_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></cost_source_ind>
                      <estimated_volume><![CDATA[100.0]]></estimated_volume>
                      <mix_defn_num><![CDATA[0]]></mix_defn_num>
                      <term_pricing_comp_num><![CDATA[27071]]></term_pricing_comp_num>
                      <event_specific_pricing_ind><![CDATA[0]]></event_specific_pricing_ind>
                      <multiplier><![CDATA[1.0]]></multiplier>
                      <price_precision><![CDATA[3]]></price_precision>
                      <period_end_dt><![CDATA[20231031000000]]></period_end_dt>
                      <actual_estimate_ind><![CDATA[0]]></actual_estimate_ind>
                      <tier_qty_periodicity_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_qty_periodicity_ind>
                      <cumulative_ind><![CDATA[0]]></cumulative_ind>
                      <period_sub_category_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></period_sub_category_ind>
                      <componentize_status_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></componentize_status_ind>
                      <tier_boundary_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_boundary_ind>
                      <hidden_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></hidden_cost_ind>
                      <round_pricing_component_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_pricing_component_ind>
                      <manual_override_ind><![CDATA[0]]></manual_override_ind>
                      <apply_precision_ind><![CDATA[1]]></apply_precision_ind>
                      <pricingComponentCount><![CDATA[0]]></pricingComponentCount>
                      <demand_charge_ind><![CDATA[0]]></demand_charge_ind>
                      <pricing_type_ind><![CDATA[1]]></pricing_type_ind>
                      <estimate_audit_num><![CDATA[19327]]></estimate_audit_num>
                      <comp_function_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></comp_function_ind>
                      <use_pricing_dt_ind><![CDATA[0]]></use_pricing_dt_ind>
                      <complex_charges_ind><![CDATA[0]]></complex_charges_ind>
                      <balance_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></balance_cost_ind>
                      <rate_override_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_override_ind>
                      <cost_type_cd><![CDATA[MTM]]></cost_type_cd>
                      <fx_rate_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></fx_rate_type_ind>
                      <quote_def_num><![CDATA[10320]]></quote_def_num>
                      <pricing_period_tier_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></pricing_period_tier_ind>
                      <tier_qty_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_qty_type_ind>
                      <time_based_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></time_based_cost_ind>
                      <ic_mirror_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></ic_mirror_cost_ind>
                      <rate_lookup_cost_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_lookup_cost_type_ind>
                      <round_pricing_rule_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_pricing_rule_ind>
                      <retain_realized_ind><![CDATA[0]]></retain_realized_ind>
                    </TermMtmList>
                    <TermDetailList table="2">
                      <mon_ind><![CDATA[1]]></mon_ind>
                      <sat_ind><![CDATA[1]]></sat_ind>
                      <end_time_period_cd><![CDATA[HE24]]></end_time_period_cd>
                      <fri_ind><![CDATA[1]]></fri_ind>
                      <trade_status_ind><![CDATA[1]]></trade_status_ind>
                      <tue_ind><![CDATA[1]]></tue_ind>
                      <term_num><![CDATA[6709]]></term_num>
                      <sun_ind><![CDATA[1]]></sun_ind>
                      <var_project_delta><![CDATA[100.0]]></var_project_delta>
                      <trade_qty><![CDATA[25.0]]></trade_qty>
                      <thu_ind><![CDATA[1]]></thu_ind>
                      <comp_sync_id><![CDATA[1]]></comp_sync_id>
                      <start_time_period_cd><![CDATA[HE01]]></start_time_period_cd>
                      <detail_num><![CDATA[8520]]></detail_num>
                      <end_dt><![CDATA[20231031000000]]></end_dt>
                      <qty_periodicity_ind><![CDATA[2]]></qty_periodicity_ind>
                      <start_dt><![CDATA[20231001000000]]></start_dt>
                      <day_offset_ind><![CDATA[0]]></day_offset_ind>
                      <hol_ind><![CDATA[1]]></hol_ind>
                      <qty_uom_cd><![CDATA[zKBBL]]></qty_uom_cd>
                      <wed_ind><![CDATA[1]]></wed_ind>
                    </TermDetailList>
                    <TermPriceList table="2">
                      <price_uom_period_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></price_uom_period_ind>
                      <common_pricing_days_ind><![CDATA[0]]></common_pricing_days_ind>
                      <price_qty_category_ind><![CDATA[0]]></price_qty_category_ind>
                      <percentage_cashflow_qty_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></percentage_cashflow_qty_ind>
                      <delivery_based_ind><![CDATA[0]]></delivery_based_ind>
                      <period_start_dt><![CDATA[20231001000000]]></period_start_dt>
                      <term_pricing_num><![CDATA[25768]]></term_pricing_num>
                      <tier_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_type_ind>
                      <implied_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></implied_cost_ind>
                      <do_not_apply_ra_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></do_not_apply_ra_cost_ind>
                      <rate_lookup_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_lookup_cost_ind>
                      <round_precision_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_precision_ind>
                      <cost_source_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></cost_source_ind>
                      <estimated_volume><![CDATA[100.0]]></estimated_volume>
                      <mix_defn_num><![CDATA[0]]></mix_defn_num>
                      <term_pricing_comp_num><![CDATA[27070]]></term_pricing_comp_num>
                      <event_specific_pricing_ind><![CDATA[0]]></event_specific_pricing_ind>
                      <multiplier><![CDATA[1.0]]></multiplier>
                      <price_precision><![CDATA[3]]></price_precision>
                      <period_end_dt><![CDATA[20231031000000]]></period_end_dt>
                      <actual_estimate_ind><![CDATA[0]]></actual_estimate_ind>
                      <tier_qty_periodicity_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_qty_periodicity_ind>
                      <cumulative_ind><![CDATA[0]]></cumulative_ind>
                      <period_sub_category_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></period_sub_category_ind>
                      <componentize_status_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></componentize_status_ind>
                      <tier_boundary_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_boundary_ind>
                      <hidden_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></hidden_cost_ind>
                      <round_pricing_component_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_pricing_component_ind>
                      <manual_override_ind><![CDATA[0]]></manual_override_ind>
                      <apply_precision_ind><![CDATA[1]]></apply_precision_ind>
                      <fixed_price><![CDATA[**92.053**]]></fixed_price>
                      <pricingComponentCount><![CDATA[0]]></pricingComponentCount>
                      <demand_charge_ind><![CDATA[0]]></demand_charge_ind>
                      <pricing_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></pricing_type_ind>
                      <estimate_audit_num><![CDATA[19326]]></estimate_audit_num>
                      <comp_function_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></comp_function_ind>
                      <use_pricing_dt_ind><![CDATA[0]]></use_pricing_dt_ind>
                      <complex_charges_ind><![CDATA[0]]></complex_charges_ind>
                      <balance_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></balance_cost_ind>
                      <rate_override_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_override_ind>
                      <cost_type_cd><![CDATA[Primary Settlement]]></cost_type_cd>
                      <fx_rate_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></fx_rate_type_ind>
                      <pricing_period_tier_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></pricing_period_tier_ind>
                      <tier_qty_type_ind><![CDATA[-1]]></tier_qty_type_ind>
                      <time_based_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></time_based_cost_ind>
                      <price_uom_cd><![CDATA[BBL]]></price_uom_cd>
                      <ic_mirror_cost_ind><![CDATA[0]]></ic_mirror_cost_ind>
                      <rate_lookup_cost_type_ind><![CDATA[0]]></rate_lookup_cost_type_ind>
                      <price_curr_cd><![CDATA[USD]]></price_curr_cd>
                      <round_pricing_rule_ind><![CDATA[0]]></round_pricing_rule_ind>
                      <retain_realized_ind><![CDATA[0]]></retain_realized_ind>
                    </TermPriceList>
                  </SwapTermList>
                </TradeHeader>
                <LockNumList table="1">
                  <lockinfo><![CDATA[TRD_HEADER 902495  1       1
    ACT_CASHFLOW    26599           1
    ACT_CASHFLOW    26600           1
    TRD_TERM    6709            1
    ]]></lockinfo>
                </LockNumList>
                <Permissions table="1">
                  <security><![CDATA[0]]></security>
                </Permissions>
              </GetTrade>
            </data>
          </mbody>
        </response>
      </return>
    </ns1:GetTradeResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have created the Document object from existing trade string that I have and also tried some code to fetch the element. But frankly speaking I have no idea how I can achieve replacing those values keeping in mind that they are to replaced inside CDATA (Although I wont mind replacing the entire node like trade_qty itself) and that too only under a particular parent.

```
private Document parseXML(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        return doc;
    }

public void readXML(String tradeResponseXML)
    {
        String replacedXML = "";
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = parseXML(tradeResponseXML);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException  | IOException xe)
        {
            logger.error("Error parsing the get response xml: ", xe);
        }

        if(doc != null)
        {
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(SWAP_TERM_LIST_XML_ELEM);
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                Element cElement =  (Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName(TRADE_QTY_XML_ELEM).item(0);
                logger.info("Qty : " + cElement.getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
```

Or Equivalent of following Dot net code:

```
For all node name like Get Trade,
    if (rootnodes.Name == "GetTrade")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode t_node in rootnodes.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (t_node.Name == "TradeHeader")
            {
                foreach (XmlNode s_node in t_node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (s_node.Name == "SwapTermList")
                    {

                        foreach (XmlNode p_node in s_node.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (p_node.Name == "trade_qty")
                            {
                                ColName = p_node.Name;
                                ColValue = p_node.InnerText;

                                sResponse1 = sResponse1.Replace("<trade_qty><![CDATA[" + Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(ColValue)).ToString() + "]]></trade_qty>", "<trade_qty><![CDATA[" + Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(s.ItemArray.GetValue(4))).ToString() + "]]></trade_qty>");//(It's lots value.)
                            }

                            if (p_node.Name == "TermPriceList")
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode k_node in p_node.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    if (k_node.Name == "fixed_price")
                                    {
                                        ColName = k_node.Name;
                                        ColValue = k_node.InnerText;
                                        errorLog.log.LogFile("COlname to update price: " + ColName);
                                        errorLog.log.LogFile("COlValue to update price: " + ColValue);
                                        sResponse1 = sResponse1.Replace("<fixed_price><![CDATA[" + Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(ColValue)).ToString() + "]]></fixed_price>", "<fixed_price><![CDATA[" + Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(s.ItemArray.GetValue(10))).ToString() + "]]></fixed_price>");// its TradePrice value.
                                        errorLog.log.LogFile("Response for fixed price : " + sResponse1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Every Element has a [setTextContent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't put XML documents into strings or encoding problems are predictable. Use byte arrays instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Jsoup is actually an html parser, but is also capable of parsing xml. It is quite intuitive and once you are familiar with the [selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) it is very easy to use. You can parse the content of your cdata to a [CDataNode](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/CDataNode.html) and use the built-in methods to get what you need.

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Using Jsoup your code to replace the values could simply look like below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.CDataNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/your/test.xml"));
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(inputStream, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());

        CDataNode trade_qty = (CDataNode) document.selectFirst("SwapTermList trade_qty").childNode(0);
        CDataNode fixed_price = (CDataNode) document.selectFirst("SwapTermList TermScrList fixed_price").childNode(0);

        System.out.println("original values");

        System.out.println(trade_qty.text());
        System.out.println(fixed_price.text());

        //replace cdata text
        trade_qty.text("5555");
        fixed_price.text("7777");

        System.out.println("replaced values");
        System.out.println(trade_qty.text());
        System.out.println(fixed_price.text());

        //if you want to save the modified document to a new file use below write, else delete the 2 lines below
        document.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
        Files.writeString(Path.of("/path/to/your/test_out.xml"), document.outerHtml());
    }
}
```

**Update**

> In case I need to replace all the trade_qty occurrences and only one occurrence of final_price (the one under parent "TermPriceList"), what can be done?

In order to select multiple elements having the same tag, use the method `select` instead of `selectFirst`. The syntax is similar, the difference is their return types, while select returns `Elements` selectFirst returns an `Element`. I don't see any tag having `final_price` in your sample xml. But if there was one the procedure is the same as with `fixed_price`.

If you want to modify a certain element, there are several possibilities you can give to the select argument. Like for example n-th child, last of its kind, first element, an element x followed by an element y and so on. Get familiar with the [selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) here.

I have duplicated the example code from earlier and modified it in the appropriate places based on your question. hope it's self-explanatory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/your/test.xml"));
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(inputStream, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());

    Elements trade_qty_elements = document.select("SwapTermList trade_qty");
    CDataNode fixed_price = (CDataNode) document.selectFirst("SwapTermList TermScrList fixed_price").childNode(0);

    System.out.println("original values of trade_qty_elements");
    trade_qty_elements.forEach(element -> System.out.println(((CDataNode) element.childNode(0)).text()));

    System.out.println("original value of fixed_price");
    System.out.println(fixed_price.text());

    //replace cdata text for example fixed_price with 777 and all trade_qty elements with 999
    fixed_price.text("777");
    trade_qty_elements.forEach(element -> ((CDataNode) element.childNode(0)).text("999"));

    System.out.println("replaced values of trade_qty_elements");
    trade_qty_elements.forEach(element -> System.out.println(((CDataNode) element.childNode(0)).text()));
    System.out.println("replaced value of fixed_price");
    System.out.println(fixed_price.text());

    //if you want to save the modified document to a new file use below write, else delete the 2 lines below
    document.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    Files.writeString(Path.of("/path/to/your/test_out.xml"), document.outerHtml());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eritrean. In case I need to replace all the trade_qty occurrences and only one occurrence of final_price (the one under parent "TermPriceList"), what can be done?

Comment: This Worked like a Treat! THANKS A TON ERITREAN :)